# Detect table cell click and set checkbox jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

This works, but only if you select the table cell, not the checkbox. Thoughts?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

        $('td.input-check-cell').click(function (e) {
            var chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').get(0);
            if (e.target != chk) {
                chk.checked = !chk.checked;
                $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

I've created a Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/x4AxV/17/

Comment: Move your event handlers in document-ready

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x4AxV/9/

Comment: Anyone? I added a fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

        $('td.input-check-cell').click(function (e) {
            var checkbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').get(0);
            if (e.target != checkbox) {
                checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
            }
            if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
                $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
            } else {
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move all your code inside the document ready event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.messages-btn-o').hide();
    $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');


    $('input:checkbox').change(function (e) {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
            $('.messages-btn-o').show();
        } else {
            $('.messages-btn-o').hide();
        }
    });

    $('td.checkbox').click(function (e) {
        var chk = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:checkbox').get(0);
        if (e.target != chk) {
            chk.checked = !chk.checked;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

It works. Thoughts?

```
        $('td.checkbox').has('input:checkbox').click(function (event) {
            if (event.target === this) {
                var $checkbox = $(this).children('input:checkbox');
                $checkbox.attr('checked', !$checkbox.attr('checked'));
            }
            if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0) {
                $('.messages-btn-o').show();
                $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('selected');
            } else {
                $('.messages-btn-o').hide();
                $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('selected');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

this will check a checkbox within the clicked cell ...

```
$('#table-id td.input-check-cell').click(function (e) {
    var checkbox = $($(this).find('input:checkbox').get(0));
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
});
```